# jQuery if condition doesn't return expected result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am confused why the if condition not producing the result 
Return result of  fxresult value = "  Call for price " this is not code and just for reference of variable result.

```
var fxresult = $(".price").html();
var fxRate = fxresult.replace(/ /g,"");   
if (fxRate == 'Callforprice'){
    alert("found") 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using the `text()` method instead of the `html()` method?

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: or maybe the `val()` method. A fiddle would help.

Comment: how does `var fxresult value = "  Call for price  "` compile?

Comment: Do we even know what element `.price` is or what it looks like?

Comment: You are missing a ; on the first line

Comment: `$(".price")` is matching on a CSS class, so jQuery will select all matching elements to the `.html()` call.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin There are way too many things missing.

Comment: @dystory text() also same result

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do? In particular, what do you expect the first line to do (what is `value` meant to be/do)? How about the lines after that? Further, what Javascript errors are you seeing in your browser's console? These would all be good starting points in fixing the code to do what you expect.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy But the var fxRate alert says "Callforprice" but it not detect to if condition, thats the problem :(

Comment: @Kevin Yes its compile

Comment: @profirdous You're going to have to post some HTML that this is running against in order for us to help any further. Otherwise, we don't know what is actually going into `fxresult`.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Thanks for trying to help.
I checked the console and test add alert.
The variable value shows "Callforprice"

Comment: In particular, does your HTML have some other whitespace character (such as a tab) before or after the string that doesn't appear in your alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may you use this regexp instead of yours.

```
var fxRate = fxresult.replace(/\s/g,"");
```

yours will work to but i think this one is a lil bit better because you avoid typos like  one whitespace or two.

and you have a typo here

```
var fxresult value = "  Call for price  "
//---------------------------------------^
```

missing a `;`

but your major problem in this line is

```
var fxresult value = "  Call for price  "
//----------^
```

you have a problem with the var declaration **(variable names can't contain spaces)**

**see working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0cs80ez7/)**

Comment: why would you point out the missing semicolon when the entire line won't compile

Comment: @KevinL you aren't supposed to compile javascript code

Comment: @kevin - i'm surprised how few people comment on that rogue "value". or for that matter, why on earth is OP testing against a regex processed string instead of basing the conditional on the value of price?

Comment: if you are not using strict mode, you wouldn't need to add a semicolon there

Comment: with this HTML layout (in the fiddle), his code is also working as expected

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking it's a problem with his HTML, not with the regexp or selector. (Using the `/ /g` regexp works just fine too in your fiddle...)

Comment: @GalacticCowboy I think he might have [added line breaks](http://jsfiddle.net/0cs80ez7/1/), that's why the space in the regexp isn't working out for him.

Comment: i know, i checked this already but there are still the other bugs